# Position library does not work in Overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

Apparently, position library of Tikz does not work in Overleaf even with its own examples, take this one: https://www.overleaf.com/read/fnmpxcrhtbdz

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Your code produces 24 errors on Overleaf. Maybe that's the issue. (You can take a look on the error messages by clicking on that small red icon right of the "Recompile" icon above the document display)

Comment: There are also small red icons with a white cross inside next to erroneous lines.

Comment: If I ignore all errors I get the same output as your overleaf document produces with an up to date TeX Live installation.

Comment: I did not produce the code, I just copied and pasted overleaf example! So is it overleaf bug?

Comment: You will have to add a version of the Ti*k*Z library `node-families` to your Overleaf project (it's also not a part of TeX Live).

Comment: It is not a bug in Overleaf (as I said, it'll produce the same amount of errors in my local TeX Live).

Comment: I just tested in Overleaf, even if you add the library yourself (https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarynode-families.code.tex) (you can either copy it from there, or use Overleaf's upload button). But even after doing this, I still get 18 errors (`unknown function x_node_dist`). Where did you get that code from?

Comment: Found the issue. You'll have to use `positioning-plus` instead of `positioning` instead. You'll find the `positioning-plus` library here: https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex (you'll have to add that one to your project, too)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I'm a freelancer working for Overleaf)

The code you're using was not coded for the `positioning` library but a custom one named `positioning-plus` (which is not part of TeX Live nor contained in Overleaf's LaTeX distribution, you can find it [on github](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex)). You'll need to add that file to your Overleaf project. You'll also need to add [`node-families`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarynode-families.code.tex) to your Overleaf project. After adding those two libraries your code should work and produce the following:

[image]

Comment: Cool, that file is in the Overleaf gallery! I probably can find the link and send it to you.